# Adding dll's to a visual studio project with browse

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio 2019 project (project.csproj), which I need to refer to an external DLL (ExampleLibrary.dll). By now, I had this library inside a folder right next to the visual studio poject. So the structure looks like this:

```
.../Project_base/Project/project.csproj
.../Project_base/Libraries/ExampleLibrary.dll
```

Whereby `...` is the path to the `Project_base` folder.
The reference to the dll was added by "add reference"->"Browse...". This worked perfectly fine. Looking at the references, a new entry appeared for the added library with the "hard coded" path `.../Project_base/Libraries/ExampleLibrary.dll`.

Now my question: Is there a way to add this reference in a less "hard coded" manner? Lets say, my coworker, does not want to have the `Project_base` folder in the same directory `...` as me. As I see it, this won't work with the actual solution, because the reference is directly pointing to a path like `C:\Example\Path\To\Base\Project_base\Libraries\ExampleLibrary.dll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Environment variables in your csproj file. So you and your coworker can set the environment Variable to a diffrent location on your system. See [is microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2022)
This may also help to use the project on a different system linke an build agent.

Than you may use:

`<HintPath>$(PROJECT_BASE)/Project_base/Project/project.csproj</HintPath>`

And set a default with

`<PROJECT_BASE Condition="'$(PROJECT_BASE)' == ''">c:\MyProjectbasePath</PROJECT_BASE>`